# Jupyter kernel uses different Python version than Conda environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, jupyter-lab, jupyter-kernel

I am not able to link Jupyter kernels to their parent Conda environments. After creating a new kernel linked to Conda environment, I'm getting a different version of Python and its dependencies inside Jupyter lab.

Here are the steps I followed:

Created a conda environment using:

`conda create -n nlp python=3.6`

`conda activate nlp`

`(nlp) ➜  ~ python --version`

> Python 3.6.9 :: Anaconda, Inc.

`(nlp) ➜  ~ which python`

> /anaconda3/envs/nlp/bin/python

Inside the environment I created a Jupyter kernel with:

`(nlp) ➜  ~ python -m ipykernel install --user --name=nlp`

> Installed kernelspec nlp in /Users//Library/Jupyter/kernels/nlp

Investigating the created json file for the kernel:

```
(nlp) ➜  ~ cat /Users/<username>/Library/Jupyter/kernels/nlp/kernel.json
{
 "argv": [
  "/anaconda3/envs/nlp/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "nlp",
 "language": "python"
}%
```

It seems to be pointing to the environment version of Python

But when I start `Jupyter Lab` and select the `nlp` kernel, I get a different version of Python and some dependencies are missing

`!python --version`

> Python 3.5.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.

`!which python`

> /anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: Does `nlp` have `ipykernel` installed? You can check with `conda list -n nlp ipykernel`.

Comment: Yes, `ipykernel` installed, the output of your command:

```
# packages in environment at /anaconda3/envs/nlp:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py37h39e3cac_0
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try the following steps:

```
conda activate nlp
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --name nlp --user
```

After these steps please try changing the kernel again in jupyter lab to "nlp".

Thanks.

Comment: This didn't work


```
(nlp) ➜  ~ conda install ipykernel

Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

(nlp) ➜  ~ ipython kernel install --name nlp --user
Installed kernelspec nlp in /Users/<username>/Library/Jupyter/kernels/nlp

```

Comment: No, it is macOS

Comment: Could you please try creating a new conda environment and try installing ipykernel in that environment using the above steps

Answer (score 0):

this behavior is actually normal in Jupyter lab.
If you run

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
!python --version
```

in a notebook, the print statement will give you the Python version of the conda env, while the second will give you the Python version of your base env.

The easiest workaround for this is to simply `pip install jupyterlab` in your conda env and then run `jupyter lab` in your conda env. Then, there will not be a mismatch in Python versions between the new "base" env and the conda env which will help clear up any DLL problems.

It's probably not best practice, but you do what you gotta do when working with legacy code, ig.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
# in base env
conda install nb_conda_kernels
conda activate nlp
conda install ipykernel
conda install ipywidgets
# install kernelspec
python -m ipykernel install --user --name nlp --display-name "nlp env"
```

When you run jupyter notebook, you will see 2 nlp kernels.  Use the one with "Python [conda:env:nlp]"